# Smarty set cache directory

Tags: php, caching, smarty

I migrate the content of a subdomain `subdomain1` under this directory  `/var/www/vhosts/Domain1/subdomains/subdomain1/httpdocs/`to a new Domain2, like that the new domain: `domain2` is an identical copy of the first subdomain.This domain is under this directory `/var/www/vhosts/domain2/httpdocs`.
The problem is once I finished copying and reconfiguring the new domain I figured out a small problem.A Warning was printed in the browser once I type my new domain url:`Warning: The sessions directory does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/Domain1/subdomains/subdomain1/httpdocs/cache. Sessions will not work until this directory has been created!`.
Despite I create this directory (the warning disapered ) the sessions didn't started and my login was denied.
I want to reset Smarty new directories, so in a php file I tried the following

```
<?php
$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->setCacheDir('./cache');
echo $smarty->getCacheDir(); 
?>
```

But once I run this I get:

```
Call to undefined method Smarty::setCacheDir()
Call to undefined method Smarty::getCacheDir()
```

Any Idea how to reset Smarty directories(cache directory)? Smarty version is 2.6.14

Comment: In smarty 2 you have to set the cache directory by a property ($smarty->cache_dir). http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/variable.cache.dir.tpl

Comment: I tried this in first place but i recieved `Call to undefined method Smarty::cache_dir()`

Comment: You tried to set the cache dir like so ? `$smarty->cache_dir = './cache'` ?

Comment: Ah it works .. I tried before like this: set_cache_dir('./cache');

Comment: but despite that the function worked.. I still have the same warning `Warning: The sessions directory does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/Domain1/subdomains/subdomain1/httpdocs/cache. Sessions will not work until this directory has been created!`

Comment: Did you delete the content of the compile_dir and cache_dir after migration?

Comment: I deleted the content of cache directory but not compile_dir(templates_c) have I to delete all the folder contetnt?

Comment: I deleted the contetnt of the two folder now but still getting the warning message

Comment: Maybe this warning is related to php sessions. If so, you could check your php.ini for `session.save-path` (http://www.php.net/manual/de/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) or set the destination in php itself with `session_save_path` (http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.session-save-path.php)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51603/discussion-between-sofl-and-amani)

Comment: Try set the directory privilege to 777 ->
chmod 777 /var/www/vhosts/Domain1/subdomains/subdomain1/httpdocs/cache

Comment: yes It is already 777